# Biblatex not generating in-text citations or references

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style

Sorry, title is vague as I don't know how to specify.  I am trying to use `biblatex` to produce a bibliography, but the references section is not produced, and all that is produced is a bold version of the reference name.

This is my MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = LuaLaTeX

%Macro Preamble
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\date{
    \today}

\title{\vspace*{-9ex}\scshape %enter title here
My cool title}      
\author{\scshape\small\bfseries %enter name here
Christopher Tatlock}

\usepackage[bibencoding=utf8,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}



\begin{document}
\maketitle


Hello, this is a reference \parencite{albert}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The output for this is

> Hello, this is a reference (**albert**)

This is my bib file:

```
@article{albert,
  title={Understanding the Life Course through Newspaper Obituaries.},
  author={Albert, Ajani Oludele and Anthony, Adegoke and Lateef, Adisa Ademola},
  journal={Indian Journal of Gerontology},
  volume={30},
  number={4},
  year={2016}
}
```

It feels like I am missing something blatantly obvious.  I appreciate any help.

I am also trying with `apacite` with similar code, but `apacite` is generating

> Hello, this is a reference *(?, ?)*

instead, with no references section.

Comment: Did you also compile your document usnig `biber`? See also [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/134144)

Comment: @leandriis I don't think I was doing so, so I added `% !BIB TS-program = biber` at the beginning of my document.  Still no luck.

Comment: you need to run separate programs first lualatex then biber then lualatex twice more, first check that it works if you run the commands directly, then if you want to know how to get your editor to run that sequence, you need to say which editor you use.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am using TeXShop.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 explains how you can set up your editor to run Biber.

Comment: You won't need the `biblatex` option `bibencoding=utf8,` with LuaLaTeX. `biblatex` assumes that the guessed `.tex` file encoding and the `.bib` file encoding is the same. You also won't need `\usepackage[english]{babel}` with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @moewe, your link helped.  Now compiling with biber and all is working well.  Also, thank you for the information about biblatex encoding.

Comment: Oh, I only just noticed that I copied the wrong line in my comment above. I meant **You also won't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with LuaLaTeX.** The line `\usepackage[english]{babel}` is stills useful no matter if you use pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. Sorry for that.